# Redis PUBLISH and order of messages

Tags: redis, real-time

If two separate clients do a PUBLISH on the same channel, can I assume that the order in which the subscribers will be informed will be respected ?

- ALL subscribers receive the fist PUBLISH msg
- then ALL sunbscribers receive the second ?

Since redis is singlethreaded it should but I want to make sure it does not process both PUBLISH in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [`PUBLISH`](http://redis.io/commands/publish) is a synchronous command. It does not return until it pushes the message to all subscribers. And different `PUBLISH` commands are naturally serialized in Redis request queue.

> **Time complexity**: O(N+M) where N is the number of clients subscribed to the receiving channel and M is the total number of subscribed patterns (by any client).